# Cannot present an interestitial ad while testing?

Tags: ios, admob, interstitial

When I attempt to test AdMob's interstitial no ad is shown.

I've used the code from Google's AdMob tutorial web page. 
Do I have to add a button to execute the action?

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.interstitial = [[GADInterstitial alloc] init];
    self.interstitial.adUnitID = @"AdMob_Publisher_ID";

    GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
    request.testDevices = @[@"2077ef9a63d2b398840261c8221a0c9a"];// divice test number
    [self.interstitial loadRequest:request];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track. So far you've created the interstitial ad and have requested a test interstitial ad from AdMob. What you need to do next is present the interstitial ad. To present the interstitial ad you simply call `[interstitial presentFromRootViewController:self]`. After this interstitial ad is dismissed by the user you would request another interstitial ad from AdMob for the next time you wish to present an interstitial ad again. AdMob has a [sample project and tutorial](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/ios/interstitial) available showing you how to handle this and other delegate methods.

Comment: Thanks Daniel for the answer, you were right, after the code create a simple botton to execute the instruction -

(IBAction) adbutton: (id) sender {
     [self.interstitial presentFromRootViewController: self];
     }

the interstitial appeared,but when I close it, and press the button again does not appear again. I guess rookie mistakes sorry helpme againt?